# How to create a regular time series in R, and how to interpretate unit time in CCF function in R

Tags: r, time-series

First of all, some context. The main goal of the code is establish lag correlation between the variable flux and its predictors (sensor1,…, sensor). The variable flux, is at the end of the process so measurements of each sensor must be related at some time-shift (lag) with the variable flux.  In order to detect this lag CCF and prewhiten are computed, between variable flux and sensor1, flux and sensor2 and so on…

The variable flux and the sensors are sampled each 5m, but for some reason sometimes this sampling is not regular so the time series are not regular.

I have two main problems with my code.

**1. First problem: I have to convert my irregular data frame to a regular one sampled each 5m, and this imply repeat the last value (I do not want interpolate), for example if the sensor was sampled each 60m I want to spread this value 12 times in order to have measurements every 5m.

2. Second problem: when I compute CCF I don’t know what the meaning of the lag is, for example if I get lag -300 as the maximum lag, how much is this in time?. There is some way to relate my time series sampling with my lag?, can I express my lag in minutes?**

My data is about one year of measurements so I sampling 2 days and over those days I compute all the calculations; when I sampling 2 days and I compute CCF with prewhiten the maximum lag is not always the same so I repeat the process about 1000 times and then I can estimate the mean maximum lag and it dispersion.

Here is an example of my data (only 40 samples).

```
       row.names  fecha                 flujo   sensor1 sensor2

2   38465   2012-07-10 03:45:00 0.9617  0.0000  0
3   38466   2012-07-10 03:50:00 0.9587  0.0000  0
4   38467   2012-07-10 03:55:00 0.9638  0.0000  0
5   38468   2012-07-10 04:00:00 0.9653  0.0000  0
6   38469   2012-07-10 04:05:00 0.9678  0.0000  0
7   38470   2012-07-10 04:10:00 1.0209  0.0000  0
8   38471   2012-07-10 04:15:00 0.9573  0.0000  0
9   38472   2012-07-10 04:20:00 0.9740  0.0000  0
10  38473   2012-07-10 04:25:00 0.9678  0.0000  0
11  38474   2012-07-10 04:30:00 0.9743  0.0000  0
12  38479   2012-07-10 04:55:00 0.9647  0.0000  0
13  38480   2012-07-10 05:00:00 1.0342  0.0000  0
14  38485   2012-07-10 05:25:00 1.1007  0.0000  0
15  38486   2012-07-10 05:30:00 1.0962  0.0000  0
16  38489   2012-07-10 05:45:00 1.0918  0.0000  0
17  38490   2012-07-10 05:50:00 1.0918  0.0000  0
18  38491   2012-07-10 05:55:00 1.1018  0.0000  0
19  38493   2012-07-10 06:05:00 0.8414  0.0000  0
20  38494   2012-07-10 06:10:00 1.0406  0.7862  0
21  38495   2012-07-10 06:15:00 1.0614  0.8123  0
22  38496   2012-07-10 06:20:00 1.0619  0.7966  0
23  38497   2012-07-10 06:25:00 1.0557  0.7713  0
24  38500   2012-07-10 06:40:00 0.8487  0.8541  0
25  38506   2012-07-10 07:10:00 0.8478  0.9849  0
26  38515   2012-07-10 07:55:00 1.0776  1.0056  0
27  38516   2012-07-10 08:00:00 1.0807  0.9735  0
28  38517   2012-07-10 08:05:00 1.0801  1.0088  0
29  38518   2012-07-10 08:10:00 1.0737  1.0576  0
30  38519   2012-07-10 08:15:00 1.01.
```

% function to generate 2 random consecutive days samples

```
matriz = function(datos){
n <- nrow(datos)
dia.aleatorio <- sample(1:(n/2), 1, replace=F)
dia.aleatorio
dia1 <- datos$fecha[dia.aleatorio]
dia1
t1 <- dia1$mda
t1
dia2 <- dia1 + 86400
dia2 <- as.POSIXlt(as.character(dia2),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
t2 <- dia2$mday
t1
t2
mes.aleatorio <- sample(1:12, 1, replace=F)
mes.aleatorio
ifelse(t1>9, p1<-t1, p1 <- paste("0",t1,sep="") )
ifelse(t2>9, p2<-t2, p2 <- paste("0",t2,sep="") )
ifelse(mes.aleatorio>9, m2<-mes.aleatorio, m2 <- paste("0",mes.aleatorio,sep="") )
fecha.elejida1 <- paste(m2,p1, sep ="-")
fecha.elejida1
fecha.elejida2 <- paste(m2,p2, sep ="-")
fecha.elejida2
molienda.dia1 <- subset(datos, format(datos$fecha,'%m-%d')== fecha.elejida1)
molienda.dia2 <- subset(datos, format(datos$fecha,'%m-%d')== fecha.elejida2)
molienda2dias <- rbind(molienda.dia1,molienda.dia2)
molienda2dias$fecha <- as.POSIXlt(molienda2dias$fecha,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
return(molienda2dias)
}
```

**# this function is not elegant but is working now**

## function to generate the matrix with 2 dias with at least 1 day of data

```
generar.matriz <- function(matriz.datos) {
  repeat {
    matriz.generada <- matriz(matriz.datos)
    numero.filas <- nrow(matriz.generada)
    # exit if the condition is met
    if (numero.filas > 290) break
}
  return(matriz.generada)

  }
```

## function to calculate max lag correlation taking in account only the abs value.

```
Find_Max_CCF<- function(a,b){
  d <- ccf(a, b, plot = FALSE)
  cor = d$acf[,,1]
  lag = d$lag[,,1]
  cor.abs = abs(cor)
  res = data.frame(cor,cor.abs,lag)
  res_max = res[which.max(res$cor.abs),]
  return(res_max)
}
```

## function to prewhiting the two time series

```
gen.lag2 = function(datos,columna){
 repeat {
    molienda.dia <- generar.matriz(datos)
    y <- xts(molienda.dia[2],molienda.dia$fecha)
    x <- xts(molienda.dia[columna],molienda.dia$fecha)
    m2a=auto.arima(x,lambda =TRUE, ic ="bic", stepwise=FALSE,approx=FALSE)
    bestOrder <- c(m2a$arma[1],m2a$arma[5],m2a$arma[2])
    m2b=arima(y,order=bestOrder,xreg=1:length(y),method="ML", optim.control = list(maxit = 1000))
    maximo.lag <- Find_Max_CCF(residuals(m2b), residuals(m2a))    
    if (maximo.lag$lag < 0) break
}
return(maximo.lag$lag)
}

I only use negative lags because my proceses must be causal
```

sometimes the solucion of prewhiting cause a singular matrix an the function stop so I create other function to avoid this problem using trycatch, repeating the procees until I got a solution

```
lag.filter = function(datos,col,p,q){  
  repeat{
    er <- tryCatch(desf <- gen.lag1(datos,col,p,q), error = function(e) "este es un error")
    if (desf < 0 | class(er) == "numeric")
      return(desf)
  }
}
```

# function to create a lag matrix for each time serie

```
matriz.desfase = function(data,nrep)
# se debe ingresar la data normal
desfases <- numeric()
for (i 3:ncol(data)){  
desfase[i-2] <- replicate(nrep, lag.filter2(data,i))
}
```

all these functions are working but, my matrix is not a regular time series so I have to find the way to create a regular 5m time serie from my matrix. and also the lag that I got is not interpretable if I do not have a relation between the lag from ccf and my time series step (5minutes in my case)

any advice will be welcome

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to convert my data to regular 5m time serie using this function

```
regular = function(x){
    index <- molienda.dia$fecha
    delta.5m <- as.POSIXct(index[1])+(0:576)*60*5
    aux.5m <- xts(rep(NA,length(delta.5m)), order.by=delta.5m)
    #x1 <-na.locf(merge(aux.5m, x)[,2])
    x2 <- merge(aux.5m, na.locf(merge(aux.5m, x)[,2]), join="inner")[,2]
    return(x2)
    }
    x <- regular(x)
    y <- regular(y)
```

and regarding the unit of time I guess is in seconds because is my time unit base